Is there something I am missing when setting up URL routes in my PHP script? Wildcard matches are routing to specific terms
I am experiencing some odd behavior with my URL routing system. I recently updated the PHP version of my server to PHP8 (from PHP 5.5), so I am not sure if it started then, or if was something that I just had never noticed prior.
Here is a rundown of the issue:
I get the expected result when I visit /login/ to my application, however, if I visit /user/login/ then it still displays my login page, versus a page for the user login.
Here is my .htaccess:
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Rewrite engine                                                     |
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
</IfModule>

Here is my simple routing:
<?php
@list($page_url,$url_vars) = explode('?',$page_url);

$rules = array(                         
    '{login/$}'                         => 'login.php',
    '{logout/$}'                        => 'login.php?action=logout',
    '{dashboard/$}'                     => 'dashboard.php',
    '{feed/$}'                          => 'feed.php',
    '{ajax/([^/]+)$}'                   => 'ajax.php?action=$params[1]',
    '{user/([^/]+)/$}'                  => 'user.php?username=$params[1]&albums=false',
);
$found = false;
foreach ($rules as $pattern => $target) {
    if (preg_match($pattern, $page_url, $params)) {
        @list($page,$query) = explode('?',$target);
        $query = preg_replace_callback('/\$params\[(\d+)\]/',function($m) use ($params) { 
            return $params[$m[1]];
        }, $query);
        parse_str($query, $url_query_vars);
        /*
        foreach ($url_query_vars as $var => $value) {
            $query_vars[$var] = $value;
        }
        */
        extract($url_query_vars);
        //print_r($url_query_vars);
        require $page;
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
}
?>

Basically, /ajax/feed/ is getting routed feed.php or /user/login/ is getting routed to login.php and I can't figure out what is causing the issue.
Anyone notice anything that may be the culprit?

Well ... login/$ will indeed match /user/login, won't it?

Does it? I was under the assumption that with the {login/$} pattern that this rule expects a literal string login/ followed by anything (represented by $) until the end (/). In the case of /user/login, the URL doesn't match the exact pattern because it's looking for URLs starting with /user/. Do I have some logic confused?

No, sorry, that is not how regular expressions work.

The regular expression login/$ matches any string that consists of "login/" without anything following after that. No limitation exists about what comes before the "login". If you wanted to limit that you'd have to say so in your expression. What you actually want here is probably something like ^login/?$ ... That would be a string that contains "login" without anything before it, a potential slash after it and nothing else following. I recommend the book on "Regular expressions" by O'Reilly, a standard. Not exactly fun, but packed with facts and examples.
